# PHP page returning the same time for every mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting time information from a database that is in 24 hour format(00:00:00). When i get it on the php page, i use:

```
$output .= date("g:i A", $result1['event_start_time']);
```

But when i check the data on my client/receiver side, all of the times are the same, right now they are all saying 6:00 PM. I event do a call to get the 'event_end_time' and it also returns the same time.

Is there any way to fix this or where this error is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `strtotime` on your database field -

```
$output .= date("g:i A", strtotime($result1['event_start_time']));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `strtotime`, refer [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$output .= date("g:i A", strtotime($result1['event_start_time']));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your event_start_time is storing the time in 24 hour format why are you converting it with a date function ?